# Sqlite dll file not found

Tags: database, sqlite

I am developing winforms application. I am using sqlite database in that application. I installed sqlite database. Also add reference of sqlite.designer, system.data.sqlite I can use database file(sqlite) in visual studio in designer view. But when program runs sqlite.sqlconnection not defined error. What I am missing. Please help

```
dim con As New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=database")
```

Comment: Is the DLL present in the Debug/Release directory? (assuming that you're using VS of course).

Comment: yes system.data.sqlite is present

Comment: yes using visual studio 2013